# How to create "AGREE Stream" for DEM Reconditioning in Arc Hydro tool?

Tags: watershed, arc-hydro

I want to deliniate streams and watershed using SRTM DEM. for this I am using Arc Hydro tool. While performing  DEM Reconditioning for DEM manipulation it asks AGREE Stream as a input.

How to create this so caled "AGREE Stream" to feed for DEM Reconditioning?

Comment: What version/license level of ArcGIS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the AGREE Stream can be any line layer that the tool will convert into raster and burn into your DEM at the width and depth that you specify in the tool dialogue.

So you can create the AGREE Stream layer by digitizing known streams/drainage from an aerial image, download an open source layer such as data from Open Street Map, or use a government produced stream layer such as the National Hydrographic Dataset in the US. I suppose in some place you could also purchase data.

I ran DEM reconditioning today with ArcHydro for 10.5, and I used my local county's stream layer as is, without any modifications, and it worked fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You Brenden M for the answer. It helped me in the right way